# Why does the asynchronous nature of Node.js make it bad for video/image manipulation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, io, cpu

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlB_eWDSMt4) at 9:42 it mentions that while Node is useful for IO-intensive apps because it does fetches/requests asynchronously, it "should not be used for CPU-intensive application like video encoding or image manipulation" because in these apps "there are a lot of calculations done by the CPU". Can anyone give me a better picture of how IP threads and the CPU are used in IO-intensive vs CPU-intensive apps? Specifically:

1. In an IO-intensive app, say you make a server request, Node has 1 thread that puts that request in the event queue. What thing takes the request from the event queue and handles it?
2. In a CPU-intensive app, why can't individual calculations by put in the event queue? Is it because each consecutive one depends on the previous one, where with IO requests they don't?

Comment: *why can't individual calculations by put in the event queue* because only "units" of code can be placed on the event queue, such as a function.

Comment: Node.js is fine for doing video / image manipulation.  What he's saying is wrong.  Especially now we have workers and WASM in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. I/O intensive: Essentially, JavaScript hands the server request over to the browser. Once the connection is made and there is data to be read, the browser will package the data and put it on the JavaScript's job queue. Generally, threads waiting on I/O have a lot of down time when they are essentially waiting for more data. This means you can run a lot of these at one time in the background, but because of all of the waiting, JavaScript can handle all of them with one thread.
2. CPU intensive: Image manipulation generally involves lots and lots of matrix transformations. These transformations can be done in parallel, so better done in a programming language that can utilize the GPU and multiple threads on the CPU. Also compiled languages that are closer to system resources (registers, memory, cache etc) can often optimize operations that JavaScript can't

Comment: Re "JavaScript hands the server request over to the browser": with Node.js, is it really the browser? I thought the point of Node was that it doesn't need to run in a browser.

Comment: True, not the browser in Node.js, but some other background job mechanism